# Are there instances when Captcha / Human validation is more necessary during registration?

Tags: registration, validation, captcha

I am not particularly asking about whether or not Captcha within itself is good UX, but a more generalized question as to when human validation truly makes a difference in terms of a website's integrity, and what "kind" of website those may be?

For example, websites (e.g. social networks) where user accounts are forward facing, and friends/groups are involved and most importantly the integrity of the website is dependent upon user generated content.

**VERSUS**

An ecommerce site where user accounts are not accessible to the general public and the end goal of the site is to convert via a credit card being used thereby ensuring that the user is a real person (in theory...).

Also are there other instances besides social networks / ecommerce, e.g. Software as a Service, where captcha is essential or not essential.

Comment: If you're not asking whether or not it's good UX, then I'm not sure it belongs on UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the positives and negatives of using a captcha. The negative is that it requires more work by the users and it is quite a significant extra piece of cognative work.

The positive is that it can avoid automated bots accessing certain features of a site. If this is more important than the inconvenience, then it is worth using a captcha. In many occasions, there are other ways in which the user is verified - credit card on an e-commerce site, or an identity check on a mobile phone site.

The time I feel they are fully justified is on email forms, where there is a chance of being used for spamming. Also, for fending off automated brute force password attacks. But I don't like them, and I think they should only be used where there is a real benefit ( in particular a benefit for the user ) of having them.

So if you can justify them as providing benefits - ideally to both sides - then use them. Otherwise - and as a default - don't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solid rule of thumb, but captchas seem most helpful wherever there's an opportunity for automated mis-use of the site. When you look at the feature set for a site, ask whether there is the potential for an automated tool to abuse those features, or otherwise violate the terms, and you'll be able to choose quickly about whether or not a captcha is helpful or unnecessary.